# Changing viewport scaling (zooming out) works only once

Tags: jquery, ios, viewport, pinchzoom

I have a problem concerning iPad's scaling.

On click the user should get a popup with an overlay, and the view shouldn't be scaled - meaning it should zoom out to scale 0.75 (basically pinch zoom out as far as it can). Therefore I apply this jQuery code to the viewport:

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1020, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.75, minimum-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=0.75, user-scalable=no');
```

And on close I reset it too the original values to enable scaling. Like such:

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1020');
```

So to reitirate:

1. User visits page, has the initial viewport content is **width=1020**
2. User clicks an element triggering the popup, user could've pinch zoomed in on the page
3. Popup event changes the viewport content so it zooms out to 0.75 *[code block #1]*
4. When popup is closed the viewport content is reset *[code block #2]*

This works fine until the user does one pinch zoom action AFTER the first viewport change,  and triggers the popup event again. Then the applied viewport attributes won't take effect, it will remain zoomed in instead of scale 0.75.

TLDR: viewport scaling out only works once :)

Appended with more code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#large-image', function() {
    $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1020, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.75, minimum-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=0.75, user-scalable=no');
    // HERE GOES CODE THAT CREATES A FIXED DIV WITH 100% IN BOTH HEIGHT AND WIDTH
});
$('body').on('click', '#zoomPinchClose', function() {
    // REMOVE THE FIXED DIV
    $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1020');
});
```

That's basically it. No styling to the body. Only a stretched fixed div being created.

Comment: Does the fixed div indeed get removed? also, is the click function being called at all the 2nd time?

Comment: Yes, it is removed. Also, I print the values after each event to see the viewport changes. They do change to the values I want, but only seem to affect the viewport once. Yes, the click functions work the 2nd time, because the popup does.

Comment: I'm going through all my code now to find the culprit. I just noticed that printing a console.log() to the popup click event only happens on the first click. BUT, manually entering $('meta[name="viewport"]') into the console shows the values being change. I'm using the iPad emulator and Safari web inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Grasping at straws here but try this

```
$('body').on('click', '#zoomPinchClose', function() {
    // REMOVE THE FIXED DIV
    $('meta[name="viewport"]').removeAttr("content");
    $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1020');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. Also it's getting really weird now:

   `console.log($('meta[name="viewport"]'));

   $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1020, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.75, minimum-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=0.75, user-scalable=no');`

Should print [<meta name="viewport" content="width=1020">] in log, but instead it prints the changed value BEFORE it has been changed by the code under the console.log()... if I put the $('meta[name="viewport"]') into a variable and log that variable it shows correct values... how can viewport be changed before change is made?

Comment: @RafaelFyen Browsers will "fix" the viewport `value="..."` parameter as required for their own sake. When you save that value in a variable, that variable is owned by JavaScript and it's not going to change.